# Laravel permission issue in windows

Tags: php, laravel-4

- I downloaded the laravel from server to my local windows8
  xampp->htdocs folder. Below is the error i am getting.

> Error in exception handler: The stream or file
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\storage/logs/log-apache2handler-2014-12-11.txt"
>   could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler.php:77
>
> I tried to give the permissions full permissions in security->full
>   control  but not changing. What should i do to solve this issue

---

I am using windows 8 with xampp latest version 3.2.1

Comment: Changed the file permissions with explorer?

Comment: `xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\storage` needs to be writable

Comment: @Matt how to make it writable in windows

Comment: @ Marco Mura !!!! can u help me how to change the permissions with explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are an admin user on that computer.

Answer (score 1):

The entire app\storage folder and its contents (including sub directories) must be writeable by the user which owns the Apache process (or everyone if you're in a testing environment)

Comment: how to make it writable in windows !!!!!!

Comment: Add everyone full control and apply to contents including subdirs.

Comment: I got the answer , in  C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\storage\logs  it  is storing as log-apache2handler-2014-08-04, etc i created a new folder and i moved all those into it . Finally it started working