# Laravel storage folder write access

Tags: windows, laravel

I saw this in a github repo. It's a laravel related configuration.

```
Ensure permissions in storage folder has write access.

$ chmod -R 755 storage
$ chown www-data:www-data -Rf storage
```

I'm using windows, do I have to do the above command?

Comment: The above commands are for Unix environment

Comment: @MayankPandeyz so it's not needed if I'm on windows?

Comment: Its needed, means write permission is required on that folder, but that command do not work on windows

Comment: Removed  php and unix tags since the question is about windows and does not directly deal with PHP. Cleaned up grammer slightly.

Answer (score 0):

A simple referencing would be from [Laravel permission issue in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428444/laravel-permission-issue-in-windows)
However, in windows, referencing the post [here](http://www.faqforge.com/windows/take-ownership-of-a-file-or-folder-by-command-in-windows/):

> If I wanted to take control of my Program Files folder, I'd need to enter the following:

```
takeown /f "C:\Program Files" /r /d y
icacls "C:\Program Files" /grant christian:F /t /q
```

> I have not really tested this on my system, but I found at least two reference pages where this is used. Just change the path to the directory, and also notice that `/r` means recursively just like `-R` for linux system.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't have error running anything without doing above command.