# FIle could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: windows, laravel-5

I am trying to start server of larvel, but I found this:

`"The stream or file "C:\Users\pa\storage\logs/laravel-2020-12-07.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied"`.

What should i do now ?? i am using windows platform.

Comment: Hi and welcome. I would first "harmonize the path" so use everywhere Windows Path Seperator `\`

Comment: Hi @paribibi have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428444/laravel-permission-issue-in-windows or you can look for 755 permission on windows. Basically it is because laravel is trying to write on the storage folder and does not have the permission .